# Windows Key when running Win 8.1 in Boot Camp on a Mac

Tags: bootcamp, windows, parallels-desktop

I'm running Windows 8.1 in Boot Camp under Mountain Lion on a MacBook Air.  I've tried every combination of Command, Option, Control and Shift and I can't figure out how to produce the equivalent of the Windows Key.
I'm also using Parallels to run the Boot Camp image of Win 8.1 in a window alongside other Mac apps, so I'm not sure if the Windows Key maps differently to the Mac keyboard under Parallels versus Boot Camp alone.

Answer (score 2):

Is this just a problem with Windows 8? With Windows 7 running in Boot Camp, the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> by itself acts as the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>. If I tap just the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>, the Start Menu pops up. If I type <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, my screen will lock.

Within Windows, you may want to check "Apple Software Update" to see if any new drivers are available. Also check the Keyboard tab in the Boot Camp control panel. In the Boot Camp control panel there is also a Help button, and one of the topics mentions that you can use the "Add or Remove Programs" control panel to remove the Boot Camp drivers if you want to reinstall to ensure a fresh installation.

Comment: Though this didn't work when I tried it before my original post, I find now that Command alone does work like the Windows key, but only partially.  If I hit Command when I'm in Desktop mode, it takes me to the Start screen and vice versa, which is what the Windows key does.  But the many key combinations, e.g., Windows-C to get the Charms bar, either don't work at all using the Command key, or they produce inconsistent results.  First time I tried Command-C, nothing happened; next time, it gave me the Search function with the letter C in the search bar.  Apple4 S/W Update shows nothing.

Comment: How do I find the Boot Camp Control Panel?  I seldom use Win 8 exclusively in Boot Camp.  Mostly I use the Boot Camp installation under Parallels and I can't find a Boot Camp Control Panel there.  I tried the Windows Control Panel, but there is no Boot Camp listing there that I can find and nothing in the keyboard section has any clues about this.

Comment: I use Windows 8 on a PC, and Windows 7 on Boot Camp, so I regret I can't offer advice on how to find the Boot Camp settings in W8. Sorry. (For Windows 7, the Boot Camp control panel is accessible in the System Tray (notifications area).)

Comment: Try accessing it directly: C:\Windows\System32\AppleControlPanel.exe